# i have made a calculator using html ,css and javascript and its not working

Tags: javascript, calculator

[HTML code

it is a simple calculator html code that's why I haven't posted it full

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET5Cu.png)
[JavaScript code :
the main issue is with the JavaScript code which needs to be focused on .

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im0ND.png)

Comment: Please [post your code here as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), images of code are not debuggable. Also, describe your issue with the code in details, what you want your code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: Sorry but i am new to this , earlier I posted the code which was a working code but I didn't understood as i was posting it gave too much errors even though the code was ok , so I though best would be to post a picture then as I desperately neededanswer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

since the script is placed in head section and the HTML content is not yet rendered it is not able to get the elements using query selectors. Try placing the script at the end of body

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze5FD.png)
[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3UMX.png)

```js
let input = document.getElementById("display");
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

let string = "";
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    string += event.target.innerHTML;
    console.log(string);
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input id="display" type="text" />
        </div>
        <button> 1 </button>
        <button> 2 </button>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great it worked now as you said the script tag placement was the problem so the content was not rendered , I placed it in the body and now it works perfectly fine , I thought my java script was the problem .